# Fwrite does not write a new line to txt file

Tags: php, fwrite

I know it must be very easy but i can't get it to work! I want a new line after $_POST['query'] is written to data.txt! I tried it with PHP_EOL but it doesn't work?

Here is my code at the moment:

```
$fh = fopen("data.txt", "a");
// Write text
$input1=$_POST['query'];
fwrite($fh , $input1 . PHP_EOL);
// Close the text file
fclose($fh);
```

Also this does not work:

```
$f = fopen("data.txt", "a");
// Write text
fwrite($f, $_POST["query"]"/n");
// Close the text file
fclose($f);
```

Thanks for help!

Comment: How are you checking this? Because fwrite will write whatever is the new line/return on your operating platform if you use PHP_EOL

Comment: i saw this on another site and tried it .. had this before:  $f = fopen("data.txt", "a");
    // Write text
    fwrite($f, $_POST["query"]);
    // Close the text file
    fclose($f);

Comment: If you are checking this by echoing the contents of data.txt to your browser, the new lines will not be displayed.

Comment: No i download the txt file with my ftp manager and open it with notepad

Comment: You may see them with a different text editor. I'm not sure if notepad will display "\n" new lines properly; it may need windows-style "\r\n" new lines.

Comment: Oh man that was it! ;D With notepad++ and in the browser i can see it! Thx

Answer (score 0):

`fwrite()` and it's associated functions are way outdated today. I recommend reading up on `file_put_contents()` and its associated functions, as they make working with files a whole lot easier.

PHP manual: http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php

Also, re-read how you're doing your concatenation.

PS: Your script is vulnerable to data-poising attacks, since you don't validate the input. For instance, is newline supposed to be allowed for the user to pass? And if so, what happens with your data structure if someone does?